# PHP Validation Form Not Showing in Localhost?

Tags: php, forms

There is no logical error, I think Just the syntax error, also this was not returning any value or something.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

[enter image description here][1]`enter code here`

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Sdy.jpg**strong text**

Comment: Hey Ammar, do you mind posting the php as well

Comment: I ll be grateful to you @JacoT

Comment: Hey Ammar, do you mind editing your question and then putting it in there formatted as code, you can just paste it in the editor box, highlight it and the  press ctrl + k, will be much easier to read that way

Comment: @jacoT can you see it now?

Comment: Yes, checking now

Answer (score 0):

You just had a space between < and php on line 45, also make sure the extension of your file is .php

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<? php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working sir

Comment: did you make the file extension .php?

Comment: Hi Amar, please remember to accept one of the answers so the question moves to answered.

Comment: Okay Sir, and thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
JUST USE DOT. PHP Extension at the last that will resolve our issue.

<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```